# Cant use android studio virtual machine

Tags: android, virtual-machine

i installed android studio and updated all the features.i created a virtual device then tried to run a simple hello world text and this the error i got

"> Task :app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE

> Task :app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
>   Task :app:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
>   Task :app:javaPreCompileDebug UP-TO-DATE
>   Task :app:compileDebugAidl NO-SOURCE
>   Task :app:compileDebugRenderscript NO-SOURCE
>   Task :app:mainApkListPersistenceDebug UP-TO-DATE
>   Task :app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
>   Task :app:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
>   Task :app:mergeDebugResources FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.

  > Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:_internal_aapt2_binary'.
  >   Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:aapt2:3.6.1-6040484.
  >    Required by:
  >        project :app
  >   No cached version of com.android.tools.build:aapt2:3.6.1-6040484 available for offline mode.
  >   No cached version of com.android.tools.build:aapt2:3.6.1-6040484 available for offline mode.
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 357ms"

i already tried what was in the "*try" section but i cant seem to get it to work.

WHAT DO I DO?

Comment: Post your build.gradle files please

Answer (score 0):

Looks like Gradle is trying to work in offline mode. Make sure you have an active, stable Internet connection and that `Offline work` is disabled in `Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Build Tools -> Gradle`

Answer (score 0):

`Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:aapt2:3.6.1-6040484`
AAPT2 (Android Asset Packaging Tool 2) has been moved to Google's Maven repository, read this:
https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/#aapt2_gmaven

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google() // make sure you have this
        jcenter()

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()  //and this
        jcenter()

    }
}
```

in build.gradle (Project)